# TP-Link TD-W8951ND port forwarding not working?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I've configured not less than 20 routers but this one is driving me crazy. I purchased a `TP-Link TD-W8951ND` modem-router and now I'm trying to configure my VoIP device to make/get calls.

This works fine so far but additionally I have a CallerID that supposedly requires ports 5060-5061/UDP and 10000-30000/UDP forwarded to the ATA device, so I disabled Firewall on my router, same with SPI, went to *Advanced setup* -> *NAT* -> chose *PVC 1* (which is the one I'm using for PPPoE), and as parameters I entered:

- Rule index: 1
- Port start: 5060
- Port end: 5061
- Protocols: Both

Something similar I've performed for 10000-30000/UDP ports. This is actually saved, but once I do a `nmap` I get:

```
rpi@rpi $ sudo nmap XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -p 5060-5061 -Pn

Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-03-14 21:57 WET
Nmap scan report for XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Host is up.
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
5060/tcp filtered sip
5061/tcp filtered sip-tls

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 4.12 seconds
```

Which should be `open` or `closed` instead. I don't know what else to try, since this seems to be a pretty simple thing and I can't figure out what else is missing. The modem-router device has factory default values in exception of the ones I've mentioned above. Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mistery solved. In my case the issue was that my internet company was blocking me all these ports. And when I say **me** I mean it - they usually don't block anything but in my case there was an issue with the configuration when the line was activated and everything was being blocked.

So, I confirm: Deactivating the firewall and SPI and using the NAT option to forward ports should work on this kind of modem-router.